# Deno equivalent to 'peek' for Reader/Conn?

Tags: deno

Is there a clean/idiomatic way to check whether any data is available for reading (e.g. in a [`Conn`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.Conn) corresponding to a TCP connection) before calling [`.read(...)`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.Reader)? If there are 1 or more bytes available then it is safe to assume that the promise returned by `read` will not stay in the pending state forever.

For context, I have just started learning Deno and am making a simple `telnet`-like script. I was originally trying to handle input from stdin (to be written out through the connection) and received data (to be displayed) in the same async function. In that case, I have to be careful not to `await conn.read(...)` because that may never resolve (other host might not send anything more). I know I can split these up or perhaps use [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) to wait for input from either one. However, I still want to know if there is something like a `peek` function/method/utility to provide this or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`BufReader`](https://doc.deno.land/https/deno.land/std/io/mod.ts#BufReader) has a `peek` method ([src](https://deno.land/std@0.99.0/io/bufio.ts#L372-409)):

> `peek()` returns the
> next `n` bytes without advancing the reader. The bytes stop being valid
> at the next read call.
>
> When the end of the underlying stream is reached, but there are unread
> bytes left in the buffer, those bytes are returned. If there are no
> bytes left in the buffer, it returns `null`.
>
> If an error is encountered before `n` bytes are available, `peek()` throws
> an error with the `partial` property set to a slice of the buffer that
> contains the bytes that were available before the error occurred.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I suppose I should've tried a little harder to find this, but at present it's not trivially easy to search the standard library API docs. Now that you mention it I was able to find my way to https://doc.deno.land/https/deno.land/std/io/mod.ts#BufReader

Comment: I had forgotten about the rendered docs; that is nice, I don't see a way to link to an individual method on a class but I've updated my answer to quote and reference the docs; thanks!